# Invalid Syntax in Python for -m pip install (...) tried everything

Tags: python, pip

I know there's a post like this, but I can't find the answer yet :S

I installed the last version of Python (3.7) and it's already come with pip right? I tried everything on CMD in intention to install libraries but everytime i got "Invalid Syntax".

```
py -m pip install ndjson;  
python -m pip install ndjson;  
pip install ndjson;  
python.exe -m pip install ndjson;
```

even `python --version` got invalid syntax.

someone help me?

my windows is 64 bits..

EDIT:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5024.png)

Comment: Can you cut and paste the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: Do you have the python path in your PATH environmental variable?

Comment: pip install ndjson didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are in your Python interpreter rather than the terminal.

Open a new terminal and try `pip install ndjson` again.

Just so you know, if you see `>>>` at the start of your terminal, you're in the Python interpreter. You can't run pip commands from the Python interpreter; you can only run them from the terminal.

To exit the interpreter you can type `quit()` (or hit control D in some systems), which will bring you back to your terminal.